# how to check if a string has english letters or not

Tags: php

there are many questions on stackoverflow that them say if a string contains **only** english letters. but I would like to know how can I to check if a string has english letters :

ex:

```
$string="で書くタッチイベント B A(フ";

if(??? $string)
    //this string has some english letters .
```

Comment: `preg_match()` and see if you can match an English letter anywhere.

Comment: Maybe something like `if (preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z]/', $string))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Example :-

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

wrt question it will be like :-

```
<?php
$string = "で書くタッチイベント B A(フ";
$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z]/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```